# Why do I get a negative time?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

In this question,

> If the second place sprinter, whose mass is $50\ \mathrm{kg}$, decelerates from his final velocity of $13.42\ \mathrm{\frac{m}{s}}$ at a constant rate over $45\ \mathrm{m}$, how long will it take him to stop, in seconds?
>
> Answer: 6.71
>
> #### Explanation
>
> Use kinematics to calculate the acceleration, which is $-2\ \mathrm{\frac{m}{s^2}}$.

assuming the sprinter is running to the right, I defined any motion opposite to that is negative. Now when I solve for my acceleration, I get $-2\ \mathrm{\frac{m}{s^2}}$. But when I look for time which is delta velocity over constant acceleration, I get a negative value for time, and that's unreasonable since time is a scalar. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using the equation
$$\Delta t = \frac{\Delta v}{a} \qquad\text{or equivalently}\qquad t_f - t_i = \frac{v_f - v_i}{a}$$
Remember, the change denoted by $\Delta$ is always final (f) minus initial (i). Be careful about which is which.

If you are careful not to mix up the final and initial quantities, your answer will make sense.

By the way, scalars can be negative. The mere fact that $\Delta t$ is a scalar doesn't mean it has to be positive. However, usually we say that final is later than initial, $t_f > t_i$, and that's why $\Delta t$ is usually positive. It's good that you noticed that a negative time difference wouldn't make sense here.

Comment: My change in velocity is 13.42 m/s (Vf is 13.42 and Vi is 0 m/s), and acceleration is -2 m/s^2, I still don't see how my answer, -6.71 could make sense, and thank you for clarifying scalars can be negative

Comment: @Willie3838 : You have the velocities wrong way round. $v_i=13.42$ and $v_f=0$. So using DavidZ's formula $t_f-t_i=\frac{v_f-v_i}{a}=\frac{0-13.42}{-2.001}=+6.71s$.

Answer (score -1):

Temperature is a scalar and can be negative. I don't know how one would have negative time, though. Anyway, instead of using -2 m/s^2, why not make it positive, since to decelerate just means to slow down, which is just acceleration?

Comment: Well, it's going against the velocity that the sprinter is going, if I made it positive then the velocity would be negative and we'd come to the same conclusion